# JGitでリポジトリクローンを行うと失敗する

Tags: java

JGitを利用してリポジトリのクローンを行を行うため、次のようなコードを記述しました。

```
Git result = Git
        .cloneRepository()
        .setBare(true)
        .setURI(remoteUrl)
        .setCredentialsProvider(
                new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(user,
                        password)).setDirectory(localDir)
        .setBranch(branch).call();
```

上記のコードを実行すると、エラーとなります。

```
java.lang.InternalError: Should not get here
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.CreateSymbolicLink0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.CreateSymbolicLink(WindowsNativeDispatcher.java:890)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createSymbolicLink(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:578)
            at java.nio.file.Files.createSymbolicLink(Files.java:1043)
            at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtil.createSymLink(FileUtil.java:111)
            at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS_Win32.detectSymlinkSupport(FS_Win32.java:171)
            at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS_Win32.supportsSymlinks(FS_Win32.java:162)
            at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.create(FileRepository.java:306)
            at org.eclipse.jgit.api.InitCommand.call(InitCommand.java:115)
            at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.init(CloneCommand.java:161)
            at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:132)
            at jp.hotpepper.ant.task.git.GitCloneTask.execute(GitCloneTask.java:59)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
```

何か設定が足りないのでしょうか？
ご教示のほどお願いいたします。

実行環境です。
Windows 7 Professional SP1 64bit
java version "1.6.0_17"
pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.201506090130-r</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JGit 4.0ではJava7が必要です。

https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/tree/stable-4.0

Comment: ご指摘の通り、使用したJGitのバージョンが問題でした。
JGitを3.4にダウングレードした結果、クローンに成功しました。
ありがとうございます。